# reading file by pickle module

Tags: python

good afternoon!
saving list(dict(),dict(),dict()) struct with pickle module, but when reading I get: <class 'function'>, and <function lesson at 0x00000278BA3A0D30>
what am I doing wrong?

```
def lesson(user, date):
    with open(user+"_"+date+".data", 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(lesson, file)
    file.close()

def read(user, date):
    with open(user+"_"+date+".data", 'rb') as file:
        lesson = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    return(lesson)
```

I am using python 3.10.7

Comment: Here is the problem: pickle.dump(lesson, file). You are passing the lesson function, instead of the data you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

"saving `list(dict(),dict(),dict())` struct with pickle module". No, you're not. You're saving the `lesson` function. See line 3 of your code.